# cURL & PHP to submit form on website

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to submit a form on lowes.com so I can get pricing for products.

I was told the simple cURL below would do this for me but I starting to think that's not the case.

There is a text box on the right side of the page. You can only get pricing for this product if you submit your zip code in that text box. I've been all over the internet and nothing has worked.

I was hoping someone could give me some advice or maybe a sample piece of code to get me started.

```
<?php
 define('POSTURL', 'http://www.lowes.com/pd_502404-46-WTW4800BQ_0__?Ntt=wtw4800bq&UserSearch=wtw4800bq&productId=50059139&rpp=32');
 define('POSTVARS', 'zipCode=90077');  // POST VARIABLES TO BE SENT

 $ch = curl_init(POSTURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($Rec_Data);

exit;
?>
```

Comment: So what's not working about it?

Comment: are you getting an error? are you getting response? try turning on headers and see if you are getting any headers back.

Comment: I would assume it enters the zipCode and I would be able to view the price of the product in the response. I'm not seeing it.